# Proving a set is a subgroup

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $G$ be an abelian group. Let $n$ be a fixed integer, and let $H = \{x \in G: x^n = e\}$. Prove that $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

---

Identity is given. Let $x$ and $y$ be in $H$. Since $H$ is abelian, $xy = yx$. It follows that

$xyx^{-1}y^{-1} = e$

$xxyx^{-1} = e$

$xyxx^{-1} = e$ since $H$ is abelian

$xy = e$

So, $H$ is closed under multiplication.

Since $xy = e, x = y^{-1}$, every element in $H$ has an inverse. So $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Please, check my work.

Comment: To show that $H$ is closed under multiplication, you need to prove that if $x^n = e$ and $y^n = e$, then $(xy)^n = e$.

Comment: It also doesn't need to be the case that $xy = e$ for all $x, y \in H$. So, you need to show that $x^{-1} \in H$, whenever $x \in H$. For example, in $C_4 \times C_4$, the elements $(1, 0)$ and $(0, 1)$ both have order $4$, but are not the inverses of one another.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't proved that $H$ is closed under multiplication. Take $x,y\in H$. Then $x^n = e$ and $y^n = e$, hence $(xy)^n = x^n y^n = ee = e$. So $xy\in H$. Also, since $e^n = e$, $e\in H$. Finally, for all $x\in H$, $(x^{-1})^n = (x^n)^{-1} = e^{-1} = e$, i.e., $x^{-1}\in H$. So $H$ is closed under inverses. Hence, $H$ is a subgroup of $G$.

Comment: How do we know from that that every element in $H$ has an inverse?

Comment: @max I thought I had that in. I must be tired :-)

Comment: @ kobe, one more question: if we redefine $H$ like $H = \{x \in G: x = x^{-1}\}$, how do we show inverse and identity? $e = e^{-1}$ , so $e$ in $H$. Inverse is given, correct?

Comment: @max you have shown that $e\in H$. To prove $H$ is closed under inverses, take $x\in H$. Since $x = x^{-1}$, $x^{-1} = (x^{-1})^{-1}$, which implies $x^{-1}\in H$.

Comment: Uh-Huh, this is very clever. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Your proof that $H$ contains $x^{-1}$ whenever it contains $x$ is not right (in addition to what kobe said). Since $x^n = e$ then you know that $x^{-1}$ is in $\langle x \rangle$, the cyclic subgroup generated by $x$, and must be some power of $x$.

Which power of $x$ does it have to be, and can you guarantee that it too has order $n$?

Comment: We didnt get around to studying cyclic subgroups just yet, but I'll be sure to think about that. Thanks.